# Using Excel to create linked tasks in TFS

Tags: excel, tfs

We have Requirement Work Items stored in TFS that we need to create Task Work Items from.  For starters we desire a single task per requirement.  Is there a way to easily create this with Excel?

For starters I downloaded the requirements into Excel, but I am not able to see how to create Task rows that link back to the original Requirement row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you use TFS 2010, it is pretty easy to create the breakdown in Excel.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293542(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

We are using TFS2015 and the procedure has changed somewhat from the 2010 version.

I followed the instructions on the [MS Docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/vsts/work/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel), but in case they disappear or just for quick reference the rough steps for adding child tasks to parent items are:

1. Make sure TFS plugin for Excel is installed (should be installed with Visual Studio).
2. Select an empty cell in a new worksheet.
3. Select the Team tab and click the "New List" button.
4. Select the relevant TFS server / project and click "Connect".
5. Select "Input List" as the type of list.
6. Click the "Get Work Items" action in the toolbar and query or enter the IDs of the parent items you're interested in.
7. Select a cell in the list and then click the "Add Tree Level" action in the toolbar.
8. In a new row directly under the desired "parent" row insert the desired title of the child item into the Title 2 column, that should have appeared after adding the tree level, you can Leave Title 1 blank.  You can set the other values as well such as "Work item type" etc.